# Uninitialized constant MercadoPago::SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

I have the following error uninitialized constant MercadoPago::SDK , this I am trying in my controller

I already put the gem of mercadopago-sdk

```
def show
    MercadoPago::SDK.client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    MercadoPago::SDK.client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here might be two things:

1. You haven't restarted your `rails server`. You will need to do this after you change your `Gemfile`.
2. A less common version of this same issue is that `spring` -- the Rails application preloader -- may be caching an older version of your application. You can restart this by running `spring stop`, stopping your `rails server` process, and then starting `rails server` again.

Comment: In my gemfile gem 'mercadopago-sdk', '~> 0.3.4' and restart the server, but that tells me